# "code": 403, "message": "Forbidden" when requesting data from YouTube Analytics API in youtube api document

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am creating an app related to customer service and marketing through social media and YouTube are the project i am working on.

I have a job to obtain ads related data from YouTube api. I need to show this data on my app so our client can make sure that their money used in promoting their YouTube channel are not wasted. i am used to work in this api social media related field but this project really give me headache.

First of all i am confused where to start to get the data i obtain. i try to see YouTube analytics and reporting data but keep getting this error when im trying their api.

[image: picture of error]

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

i has enable the Youtube analytic and reporting api on my console

[image: my active api]

The coding language that i think i wii use is php so it will be great if you can give sugestion.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code specifically your authentication code and what methods you are calling.

Comment: @DaImTo i havent code anyhting i just try using youtube api through their document to gets my ads performance but it return error as you can see in the picture. the youtube api that i already use on my api are youtube data api v3 which i dont have any question about and not related to this question. or can you give me suggesstion ?

Comment: **The coding language that im using right now is php.**  <-- please show the PHP code.   Forbiden probably means that the user you are using doesnt have access to any YouTube Analytics accounts.   What makes you think that YouTube Analytics stores information about ads performance on YouTube?

Comment: @DaImTo sorry for misleading description. i still triying it in youtube document here https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22metrics%22%3A%22views%2CestimatedRevenue%2CestimatedAdRevenue%2CestimatedRedPartnerRevenue%2CgrossRevenue%2CadImpressions%2Ccpm%2CplaybackBasedCpm%2CmonetizedPlaybacks%22%2C%22dimensions%22%3A%22day%22%2C%22startDate%22%3A%222014-05-01%22%2C%22endDate%22%3A%222014-06-30%22%2C%22ids%22%3A%22channel%3D%3DMINE%22%7D just like my image. havent code it yet since i dont think i can use it yet because of the error

Comment: @DaImTo but i intent to use php code language